# How to check if app is running on Tomcat 7 embedded?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, embedded-tomcat-7

I have a application that runs as war or in standalone mode with tomcat embedded, I want to check if the application is running as a war within tomcat or if it is running with tomcat embedded.

Comment: May be this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890504/how-to-check-if-tomcat-runnning-using-embedded-tomcat

Comment: Sorry I don't want to check if Tomcat is online but what Tomcat is running.

Comment: If You know where the application is running, You can grep through list of processes and find tomcat. Should You see `catalina` in the process command, then its probably standalone tomcat. You can also check if Your application is in `webapps` directory in tomcat location.

Comment: A bit generic question, do you want to know from the OS, from inside the app?

Comment: If all is under  your control the safe way is to add a parameter at starting `java -Druns.embedded ...` o similiar and retrieve/check in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution.

```
String path = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile();
boolean onWar = path.contains("WEB-INF");
```